# SAS Proc SQL VERY SLOW

Tags: sas

I have three tables:

- Main table that contains the `profit` per id, year and month;
- Table that contains the `tax_a` per id, year and month;
- Table that contains the `tax_b` per id, year and month.

`profit` already is acumulated by id, year and month, but the taxes aren't. I tried to do that with the solution below, it works but it's very slow. How can I approach this problem more efficiently?

```
proc sql;    
create table final_table as    
select t1.id, t1.year, t1.month, t1.profit,         
 (select sum(t2.tax_a) from work.table_tax_a t2     
  where ((t2.year = t1.year and t2.month <= t1.month) or (t2.year < t1.year)) and t2.id = t1.id) as tax_a,    
    (select sum(t3.tax_b) from work.table_tax_b t3      
     where ((t3.year = t1.year and t3.month <= t1.month) or (t3.year < t1.year)) and t3.id = t1.id) as tax_b     
from work.main_table t1;    
quit;
```

Comment: How many records are in the three source tables?  Define 'very slow' - how long does the query run for?

Comment: Also in tax_b you have `and t2.id=t1.id`, is that present in the actual code? Seems like a typo, should be `t3`.

Comment: It was a typo, already corrected. It takes arround 10 minutes (sometimes an error occur before it ending). t1 has ~3 million, t2 ~10k and t3 ~100k

Comment: is your purpose to calculate the total cumulative tax for each id/month/year combo?  I don't know the business purpose, but it so, you can just calculate the cumulative amount outside SQL and join it on.   This is slow because you are running 2 summations for each row in the `main_table`.  If you can pull that out of the join and into a temporary table, you can make this run much faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is slow because you are running 2 summations for each row in the main_table. If you can pull that out of the join and into a temporary table, you can make this run much faster.

Your inner queries are just creating a cumulative sum of the tax for each ID through time.

```
select sum(t2.tax_a) 
   from work.table_tax_a t2     
   where ((t2.year = t1.year and t2.month <= t1.month) or (t2.year < t1.year)) 
     and t2.id = t1.id
```

The `(t2.year < t1.year)` means you are doing this total across years.  If that's your reason, calculate the cumulative sum outside SQL and join the results back.

Assuming your table is sorted `by id year month`

```
data temp_a;
set table_tax_a;
by id;
retain c_tax_a;
if first.id then c_tax_a = 0;
c_tax_a = c_tax_a + tax_a;
run;
```

Do this for `table_tax_b` creating `temp_b`.  Then join them in SQL;

```
proc sql noprint;
create table final_table2 as 
select t1.id, t1.year, t1.month, t1.profit, t2.c_tax_a as tax_a, t3.c_tax_b as tax_b
    from main_table as t1,
         temp_a as t2,
         temp_b as t3
    where t1.id = t2.id
      and t2.id = t3.id
      and t1.month = t2.month
      and t2.month = t3.month
      and t1.year = t2.year
      and t2.year = t3.year;

quit;
```

Some test data shows identical results to your method.  My SQL step takes 0.03 seconds and yours takes 0.65 seconds.